# Why does conf.set("spark.app.name", appName) not set the name in the UI?

Tags: apache-spark

I am calling

```scala
val appName : String = arguments.getNameFromConfig

val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "30G")
conf.set("spark.app.name", appName)

println("Master: " + arguments.getMaster)

conf.setMaster(arguments.getMaster)    

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

in order to identify my jobs in the UI more easily. However, it does not use this name in the scheduler. Instead it is using the path to the main class `Word2VecOnCluster`:

[image]

The name is only present in the title:

[image]

A colleague of mine is actually doing the same and there it works. What you cannot see here is that the name of my task is a little larger:

> W2V_rtype-yelp_w2vpart-1_vsize-100_lr-0.025_dskeep-5.0perc_vocabsize-100000_epochs-1_iter-1

So could it be that there is a limit regarding the length of the name? If so then it might should be added to the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties) - or is there any other reason why it would do that?

Comment: because it sets the name in the spark ui and not yarn.

Comment: @eliasah Okay? Sorry I am rather new to this - what would I have to do to set the name in the "All Applications" view? Is that possible programmatically?

Comment: Two questions: are you using yarn-client or yarn-cluster mode? And are you by any chance setting the app name in the configuration _after_ starting the SparkContext?

Comment: @TzachZohar `--deploy-mode` is `cluster` and no, I am setting the configuration *before* I create the `SparkContext`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When submitting the application in **cluster** mode, the name which is set inside the sparkConf will not be picked up because by then the app has already started. You can pass **--name {appName}** to the spark-submit command to show that name in the Yarn resource manager.

Comment: Hi @Dinesh, just curious, how do you tell that it is a "cluster" mode, not a "client mode"? I have difficulty telling the difference from the above question and I believe the difference matters, as there is a lot of configuration difference. thanks!

Comment: If the mode is not passed along with the spark submit command then it picks up the default value set in the spark configs file. There isn't much configuration difference if you specify the --name property in the spark submit then that will be picked up in cluster or client mode.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE

```
conf.set("spark.app.name", appName)
```

but instead try code below:

```
spark.sparkContext.appName = appName
```

Comment: If you [edit] your answer to add an explanation, it will make it more valuable to others.